# Return item name from ExpandableListView after onClick as String

Tags: android, textview, expandablelistview

So I am trying to get the name of the child item as a string so that I can add it to other data that I collected and insert it in to a database but this method does not work, all I get is the name of the parent.

```
 exp_list.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            TextView the = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.child_txt);
            String tx = the.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), tx + " Child Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // Store value in sharedPreferences();

            Intent l = new Intent(CategoryActivity.this, AddRecipeActivity.class);
            startActivity(l);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the data (your String) from the adapter not the view:

```
    exp_list.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() { 
             @Override 
              public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) { 

                String tx = parent.getExpandableListAdapter().getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);// this will return your child Object (i guess String in your case)
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), tx + " Child Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // Store value in sharedPreferences();

                Intent l = new Intent(CategoryActivity.this, AddRecipeActivity.class);
                startActivity(l);
                return false;
            }
        });
```